# How to place a ax.text on matplolib figure using x_loc as datetime object

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I try

```
ax2.text(x=datetime.datetime(2016,1,1),y=0,s='Voila')  
TypeError: a float is required
```

while at the same time I can change color of regions in the same plot using datetime objects as xlocation.
`ax2.axvspan(datetime.datetime(2016,1,1) ,datetime.datetime(2018,1,1), facecolor='gray')`.
How to place text on plots using datetime as xlocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your datetime object to a number. For this you may use the inbuild mechanism [`matplotlib.dates.date2num`](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.date2num)

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

ax.text(mdates.date2num(datetime.datetime(2016,1,1)), 0, "Voilà")
```